# Can I learn about the reproduction process of the opposite gender in school?

Tags: sex, science, education, school

I am a young boy and in school they teach us about the female body and the male body.

We started learning about growth and development and was wondering if I am allowed to learn about the female orgasm for my own knowledge.

Only problem is that it uses a diagram. I don't know if I should not learn about it.

**There is a Netflix documentary explaining the “female orgasm” better in depth but I don't know if it would fall under Zina.** Please do help me may Allah set help all of us and keep us safe ameen.

Comment: [Stack exchange terms of service require that you be at least 13 years of age to use this site.](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#age)

Comment: Is your question whether it is allowed to learn such stuff in school from a qualified teacher or from a social outlet without any adult supervision? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Brother, this knowledge will not benefit you in any way, because the individual naturally learns such stuff when he gets older, and getting into such detail in a young age does one's mental clarity and lust more harm than good. I'm afraid this opens the doors of zina wide open and don't forget The Prophet's ﷺ Hadith: "Every son of Adam has inevitably been afflicted by fornication; for the zina of the eyes is looking, the zina of the hand is touching, and one's self wishes and desires, and the private parts confirm that or deny it."

So I would advise you to not watch such filthy stuff to not stain your virtue, as that can affect your personality and purity, and most importantly to always remember, **always**, that Allah Subhanahu Wa Ta'ala is watching you as he is The All-Seeing and The All-Knowing.

Comment: What if it is being taught from a medical point of view? After all, many medical professionals  learn to gain knowledge. Also due to the extreme taboo of learning about the opposite gender, we today have 30 year or 40 old ,males who have no idea of what even mensuration is   ... many are even ashamed to buy pads to for their younger sisters due to such societal pressures .. IMHO it all depends on the intention ... Muslims in the golden era always pursued both knowledge of dunya & deen within the limits described by our deen.